# Unresolved Functions While Working With QSslSocket

Tags: qt, openssl

I tried to run a simple program that is written with Qt and uses QSslSocket.

I'm running this program on a Ubuntu 12.04 machine with **OpenSSL installed**.

But I got the following errors:

```
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
```

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: Try to copy `libcrypto` and `libssl` to location from where you start the app

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Install the latest openSSL version.
`yum install openssl` ,`yum install libssl-dev.`.

And add QT += network in your .pro file

Source:http://codeblog.vurdalakov.net/2009/11/solution-qsslsocket-cannot-call.html

Comment: Where is `.pro` file located ? I am using Qt with VisualC++

Answer (score 35):

On Windows/MinGW you need to copy these files to your exe directory.

```
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\opt\bin\libeay32.dll
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\opt\bin\ssleay32.dll
```

Or you can copy them to `C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin` if you want it to work with all your apps. Obviously you need to distribute them with your program.

You actually *don't* need to add `QT += network`.

Comment: That's why I love SO. For your reference, the latest Qt/MinGW have these DLLs in the `\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\opt\bin`.

Comment: Interesting is dll files must be exactly in the exe directory, adding to working directory doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with QT 5.0.1 and QT 5.1.1, and finally I realized I need to copy OpenSSL DLL files next to the application binary file. For some reason QT do not load the DLL files from Windows Path ...

I've used `OpenSSL Win32 0_9_8y`

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu or (Debian based Linux) install openssl and libssl-dev

i.e. **sudo apt-get install openssl libssl-dev**.

For Red Hat , Fedora , CentOS (rpm based linux) install openssl and openssl-devel

i.e. **yum install openssl openssl-devel**

Answer (score 2):

I downgraded OpenSSL to version 1.0 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include this file:

```
 #include <QtNetwork>
```

And in your `.pro` file, add this line:

```
 QT += network
```

Comment: Thank u ! But If I hadn't done these steps, I couldn't even use QSslSocket itself.

Comment: You can use `QSslSocket` without `+= network` - if you use `QWebView`. That said, the problem isn't caused by the lack of `+= network`; it is because of the missing OpenSSL DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

Installing lua-openssl package on debian seems to have solved the issue for me.