# QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function

Tags: c++, qt, qsslsocket

I am running Qt 5.7.1 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit) with Qt Creator 4.2.0. I have a problem with `QSslSocket`. I am getting the following errors:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
```

I have gone to the following location [openssl github](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) and downloaded the zip file. I have moved the "libeay32.dll" and "ssleay32.dll" files to my release directory, and I am still getting these errors. Is there anyone who has gotten the `QSslSocket` working that can give me steps to get the socket working or has any suggestions?

Comment: drescherjm, thanks for the quick response.  Is that something i specify in the .pro file? And where do I find the .lib? I have OpenSSL-Win32 on my local disk (C:), but there are no .lib files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unresolved Functions While Working With QSslSocket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846536/unresolved-functions-while-working-with-qsslsocket)

Comment: Sorry, I  thought that was a linker error not a runtime error. I believe this message this is due to the plugin usage in Qt.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. Do you have any suggestions for how to fix runtime errors? I have looked an the previous topic "Unresolved Functions..." but I believe I tried  the solution they suggested (copying the dlls to the release folder) and it didn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Did you add `QT += network` to your pro?

Comment: yes, I do have that in my .pro file

Comment: It may sound basic but, are you executing the release configuration? I mean, if you are executing the debug configuration then you should copy the DLLs to the debug directory too. On the other hand, are you using the same version of OpenSSL libraries for which your Qt distribution was compiled?

Comment: did you manage to solve it? i have same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to Add support to OppenSSL manually, since android dropped the support of it, and i am using QT 5.9 and its not make it for you
so its your mission to create openSSL lib

You can download it directly here
https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries

or here https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

and then copy these filed and include them to your project

```
libcrypto.so
libssl.so
```

That should work correctly

Or you can generate your `libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so` using this script
, just follow it step by step
https://github.com/ekke/android-openssl-qt

Comment: https network requests work fine in Qt Android 4.4 app.  @mohammad alabid , do you know when Android dropped support? Android >= 6.0 ?  On Android 7.0 the same Qt app fails "qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_ctrl" even though I can see *both* ib.libcrypto.so and libssl.so in the Android /system/lib/ directory?

Comment: Yes support for SSlSockets dropped in Android,
 Did you tried to build .so files? you can try these files  https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6cm09niyj185fb/openSSL.zip?dl=0
-add those 3 files beside .pro file
-and add this line to your .pro file include(android-openssl.pri)

Comment: Be sure to use openssl 1.1 as openssl 3 has deprecated these functions :/

Answer (score 11):

I ended up here via Googling around. In my case, I was getting this error *on random machines* because they were missing the correct versions of `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`. It's "random" because some computers have these loaded in `PATH` from other software and some do not.

I fixed this for Qt Creator by adding the DLLs to the `bin` folder of my Qt install, and I fixed this on distributions by including the aforementioned DLLs in my distribution.

The DLLs should be the same or similar to the version of OpenSSL that Qt was compiled with in the first place. If you didn't compile it yourself, starting in Qt 5.4 you can query this with [`QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslsocket.html#sslLibraryBuildVersionString). (Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42297296/1666676)

Don't forget that your 64-bit apps should have a 64-bit version of the DLLs, and 32-bit apps should have 32-bit DLLs so you don't have the same problem as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39497754/1666676).

---

Additional notes:

- Starting in Qt 5.2 you *must* use version 1.0.0 or newer. 0.9.8 doesn't work any more. (Source: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ssl.html)
- For my standard MSVC2017x64 distribution of Qt 5.10.1 `sslLibraryBuildVersionString()` returned "OpenSSL 1.0.2o". I use 1.0.2p for my distributions.
- The OpenSSL DLLs changed names to `libcrypto-1_1*.dll` and `libssl-1_1*.dll` starting in OpenSSL 1.1.0. Standard Qt distributions don't yet use those as of Sept. 2018.
- OpenSSL GitHub downloads are here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tags

Hope this helps the next person. Sorry for resurrecting an old post.

Comment: "Of course, you should ensure that you're packaging the same DLLs as the version of OpenSSL that Qt was compiled with in the first place." How do I do this?

Comment: Good question! I found a hint to that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39497754/1666676) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42297296/1666676). In short, use `QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString()`. I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Copy these two file to path:  'C:\Qt\Tools(msvc/mingw){version}\bin'

```
C:\Qt\Tools\(msvc|mingw)\opt\bin\libeay32.dll
C:\Qt\Tools\(msvc|mingw)\opt\bin\ssleay32.dll
```

Comment: Not sure it was the issue with MSVC, but definitely was for MinGW :)

Answer (score 0):

By combining existing answers here and some research I managed to make it work with MSVC2017 x64 compiler:

1. Download 1.0 version (Win64 OpenSSL **v1.0.2r** Light) from here:
   https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
2. When installing, choose to copy DLLs to OpenSSL bin directory.
3. And then copy **libeay32.dll** and **ssleay32.dll** from OpenSSL bin folder to: `{Your_Qt_Folder}/{Qt_version}/msvc2017_64/bin`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

1. Download and install **v1.0.2s** <<--(`libeay32.dll`, `ssleay32.dll`) at https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
2. Copy `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`
3. Find `QtNetwork*.dll` in your Qt folder. In my case, path is `C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin`.
4. Paste `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` in `C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin`.