# "QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_server_method" with Qt5.7 on Windows 2016

Tags: openssl, windows-server-2016, qt5.7

I have created an application in QtCreator that runs as a service.
It uses openssl to encrypt communications between client-apps and the server.

When I install the server-application on a clean Windows server 2012 R2, everything works just fine.
But if I install it on a clean Windows server 2016, I get sslsocket errors when I start the service.
Here´s what show up in my logs:

> QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_server_method
>   QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
>   QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
>   QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
>   QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error

I have libeay32.dll and sslea32.dll in the applications root folder.
I use QtCreator 4.2.0 with Qt5.7.1 and openssl 1.0.2h.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: [Unresolved Functions While Working With QSslSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10846536/608639)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried all of that. The thing is that it´s not working on Win Server 2016 but the exact same installtion works on Win Server 2012.